# What is the purpose of GraphComputation`MeshGraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, undocumented, built-in-symbols

When I use `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` to print its definition,I will get this information:
[image]

So I think this function can convert a `Graphics` into `Graph`.But I cannot achieve it.

```
graph = RandomGraph[{5, 6}];
GraphComputation`MeshGraph[Show[graph]]
GraphComputation`MeshGraph[
 GraphComputation`GraphConvertToGraphics[graph]]
```

All will give error information.What on earth this function design for?

Answer (score 2):

Well,I believe this is bug or unfinished function now.When I get the page of `` GraphComputation`GraphBuilderDump`graphicsToMeshInfo ``

```
graphicsToMeshInfo[gr_Graphics] := Block[{mesh},
    mesh = Quiet @ MeshObject @ gr;
    If[!MeshObjectQ[mesh],
        mesh = $Failed,
  mesh = {mesh @ "SparseAdjacencyMatrix", mesh @ "VertexCoordinateRules"};
 ];
 mesh /; UnsameQ[mesh, $Failed]
];
```

But the function `MeshObject` show a undefined status(with blue color).And the varibale `mesh` is judged by `MeshObjectQ` in following step.So I think the undefined function `MeshObject` play a key role,which convert a `Graphics` into `MeshObject`,that same to `` Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject `` work on a `Region`.Maybe we will see the function in future verion.